# How to obtain value from an object (c#/xamarin)

Tags: c#, object, xamarin

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQTXY.png)

Hello. I am using xamaring forms to create an app and I am having problems obtaining a certain value from an object.
Essentially I would like to take Address1 from the object e.SelectedItem and place it into a string called address. I plan to do this to all the variables in the object, so address, city, country, postal code, etc...
From here I will use these strings to form a url link that will take the user to their native map application with the address inputed into the url.
**Note:** The line of text I have `var item = e.SelectedItem;` was added for testing purposes. 
Below I have some code:

```
async void AddressItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                var item = e.SelectedItem;
            }
        }
```

In summary: I would like to take the variables stored in an object and place them into their own string element.

Thank you!

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my suggestion would be cast your item NOT as "var", cast it as your exact class type.

```
Class item = (Class)e.selectedItem
```

Comment: I tried this however when I go to reference Address1, it gives the error: EditContact does not contain a definition for Address1

Comment: try this, put a break point on e.selecteditem line. when you pass the line just check the values of selecteditem with debugger.(when you go ON it with your mouse pointer it gives you the inside values. then see what type is this item, what is the value etc. ). you have to run it in debugger mode!!

Comment: Hey, turns out I indicated the wrong type. Thank you it works now!

Answer (score 3):

you need to `cast` the object to the correct type first

```
var item = (MyClass)e.SelectedItem;
var addr1 = item.Address1
```

Comment: I tried this however I am getting an error stating 'EditContact' does not contain a defintion for 'Address1'. Any ideas? Ty.

Comment: is `EditContact` the correct type?  From your screenshot item is appears that it's called  clsAddress